# Java error when running a .sh file for Java Bytecode Editor (Mac)

Tags: macos, java

This is for a Mac. I'm trying to install the Java Bytecode Editor (http://set.ee/jbe/). Whenever I run the jbe.sh file, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ee/ioc/cs/jbe/browser/BrowserApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ee.ioc.cs.jbe.browser.BrowserApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I installed the latest version of Java.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that this class is not java.*, javax.*, sun.*, com.sun.* or etc. It's not fault of the Java Virtual Machine or your Mac. It's the problem of installer (or you).

Open terminal, go to correct extraction folder (mine is ~/Downloads/jbe) and enter:

```
java -cp bin ee.ioc.cs.jbe.browser.BrowserApplication
```

Look what is the result:

[image]